# Jenkins testing setup and test in every push for main project or testing code push

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have to test the project code using Jenkins. In Jenkins, I am using automation testing throw selenium. then my question is I have test scripts on my laptop and using Google Cloud virtual machine SHH i have to set up and test in every push on git. Here is my 2 demand-
 1. on demand-whenever we want all the test run we should just trigger the test run.
 2. Whenever we deploy something on staging then test all the test cases

Answer (score 0):

Regarding (1), you are always able to trigger a job manually through the Jenkins UI. No special configurations there.

Regarding (2), you can install a plugin that will integrate webhooks functionality into Jenkins. In my case, I like to use [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) for this purpose, as it has the flexibility that I need on my setups.

In order to trigger the job on every deploy to staging, and assuming that your deploys are automated, you will need to add a final step on the deploy script, to make an HTTP request to the webhook URL (eg. `JENKINS_URL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=<your-token>`

I don't fully understand your setup with your machine and the VM on GCloud, in any case, I believe that the test code should be available to the machine running the tests, and not be stored in a location that might be unavailable when the tests need to be run (as your laptop might be).